# How to transpose column to row and duplicate the original column header?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table for example as below, the alphabet is header and the numbers are its records

```
a   b   c   d   e   f
---------------------
3   4   5   6   2   3
5   3   2   9   8   7
```

I want to transpose the table to be like below:

```
col1 col2
---------
a   3
b   4
c   5
d   6
e   2
f   3
a   5
b   3
c   2
d   9
e   8
f   7
```

This is not just transposing from col to row, but I also need to copy the alphabet header to as many as the original row (If I have 2 original rows then I need to copy the header twice, if I have 3 then I have to copy 3 times). I'm new in postgresql, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a lateral join:

```
select v.*
from t cross join lateral
     (values ('a', a), ('b', b), ('c', c), ('d', d), ('e', e), ('f', f)
     ) v(col, val);
```

Compared to the `union all` approach, this only scans the table once.  This can be a bit performance win if your "table" is really a more complex query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT 'a' col1,
       a col2
       FROM elbat
UNION ALL
...
UNION ALL
SELECT 'f' col1,
       f col2
       FROM elbat;
```

Comment: what is `...` ? do I have to repeat it 6 times? What if I have more than 100 columns?

Comment: An [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis#In_mathematical_notation) in the sense of "To indicate the omission of values in a repeated operation ..." just not in one line but over several lines here.